# invalid json format of facebook graph api

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, urllib2, simplejson

I am using graph api to fetch ad audiences information, when i tried https://graph.facebook.com/act_adaccountid/customaudiences?fields=

but when i tried it through a program i am getting invalid json format

---

```
      from urlib2 import urlopen
      from simplejson import loads
      x = loads(urlopen('https://graph.facebook.com/act_adaccountid/customaudiences?fields=<comma_separate_list_of_fields?access_token='XXXXXXXXXX').read())
```

output:

---

```
     {'paging': {'cursors': {'after': 'NjAxMDE5ODE5NjgxMw==', 'before': 'NjAxNTAzNDkwOTAxMw=='}}, 'data': [{'account_id': 1377346239145180L, 'id': '6015034909013'}, {'account_id': 1377346239145180L, 'id': '6015034901213'}, {'account_id': 1377346239145180L, 'id': '6015034901013'}, {'account_id': 1377346239145180L, 'id': '6015034900413'}
```

{'data': []}

expected output:
http://pastebin.com/5265tJ8w

Comment: What in the response is invalid? Have you filed a bug if you're sure this isn't working according to the documentation?

Comment: @igy i tried validating json using tools such as http://jsonlint.com i got following error: Parse error on line 1:
'paging': {    'cur
^
Expecting '{', '['

Comment: @Igy how to use the audience sharing api through urlib and what are attributes need to supply, i tried it in graph api explorer got error 803  https://graph.facebook.com/{audienceid}/adaccounts